# Browsersync error - Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

The part of gulpfile is

```
gulp.task('serve',['sass'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "dev.cz/project"

    });
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src + '**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
```

it gives me error

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
```

The project is on out local server, I am connected to server via ssh. Everything works fine, until I take broswerync to the party. Any idea ??

Comment: what is the port number you are using.. try using something other than 80 or 8080.. may be 8081

Answer (score 3):

This is probably an error because BrowserSync don't have permission to open a browser page for some reason.

adding the property    open: false will solve this